# One of my friends recently argued with me regarding the correctness of the follow statement

Tags: grammaticality

> Mohit and Sid being cunning.

I want to know if the above sentence is grammatically correct.

PS: Mohit and Sid are the names of 2 people.

Comment: It is a grammatically correct phrase, but it is not a sentence.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a complete sentence since being is a gerund and not serving as a verb.

You could say

> Mohit and Sit are cunning.

or

> Mohit and Sit are being cunning.

and those would be complete sentences.

Comment: The phrase "Mohit and Sit being cunning" would have to be followed by something, e.g. "Mohit and Sit being cunning, they soon found ways to disobey the teacher".

Comment: A phrase is also fine if it follows something else in dialogue. "What are you talking about?" "Mohit and Sid being cunning." In that context, there is no reason that the response to the question has to be a fully formed sentence. (The missing subject and verb are assumed.)